# Is there a specific name for parallel line segments that are the same length and aligned?

Tags: geometry, terminology, rectangles

I'm trying to name an algorithm that identifies line segments with the following properties.

1. They are parallel.
2. They have the same length.
3. Their endpoints are aligned along the perpendicular axis.

In other words, if you connected them, they would form a rectangle.

Is there a specific name for parallel lines with these properties?

Edit: I've taken to calling lines with this property "co-rectangular"

Comment: You could describe them as "opposite edges of a rectangle".

Comment: Without the third property, you would only get a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

It is a particular case of "equipollent line segments".

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry).